# Changing all LDUR to an ADD and a LD

Tags: assembly, arm, armv8

Consider a change to the single-cycle non-pipelined processor that executes the following instructions: `LDUR`, `STUR`, `R-type` and `CBZ`. Consider a modification that replaces the `LDUR` instructions with the pair of new instructions in the following manner:

Original code:

```
LDUR X1, X2, #100 /* X1=mem[X2+100] */
```

New code:

```
ADD X4, x2, #100 /* X4=X2+100  */
LD  X1, X4       /* X1=mem[X4] */
```

I'm being asked about the possible advantages and disadvantages. 
I can see the disadvantage of turning one instruction into 2 on a non pipelined processor. I can't seem to find any possible advantages.

Does anyone know of possible advantages of doing it this way?

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380704/deleting-a-valid-question-on-purpose)

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that comes to my mind are offsets, but I have a gut feeling there might be something extra hidden, since the question comes from academic person. However:

`LDUR`'s possible offset is in the range of -256 to 255. `ADD`, on the other hand, has a bigger offset range of 0 to 4095, which allows you to implement a function to work with bigger static offsets.

Doc:

[ARM Architecture Reference Manual ARMv8, for ARMv8-A architecture profile](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/da/DDI0487D_a_armv8_arm.pdf)

Reference:

`ADD`: C6.2.4 (page C6-698)
`LDUR`: C6.2.155 (page C6-978)